# Question from SCJP test

Tags: java, scjp

Question from SCJP test:

```
 class A{
      A aob;
      public static void main(String args[]){
           A a=new A();
           A b=new A();
           A c=new A();
           a.aob=b;
           b.aob=a;
           c.aob=a.aob;
           A d=new A().aob=new A();
           c=b;
           c.aob=null;
           System.gc();
      } 
  }
```

Question: after `c.aob=null` is executed, how many objects are eligible for garbage collection.

I think that 1, but correct answer 2. What's wrong?

Comment: @slead - You'll find the preview pane quite useful when editing and posting questions!

Comment: I updated the question to actually include the question (found by Googling).

Comment: Cripes these questions suck.  I thought the whole idea of the 'advanced', automatically garbage collected language was that I didn't have to care about this crap anymore.  Maybe I'll switch back to 'C', at least I knew that I had to care when things were going to be gc'd.

Comment: This question is about understanding what d=new A().aob=new A() does, not about understanding the details of garbage collection (you just need to know the basic way garbage collection works).

Comment: @kevindtimm, consider switching to a functional language like Haskell.

Comment: @Thorbjørn - and compete for that one job?  ;)

Answer (score 5):

From Googling I found [this thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/417827/Programmer-Certification-SCJP/certification/about-GC).

> The first object is the one referenced originally by c.
>
> A a= new A();
>       A b= new A();
>       A c= **new A()**;
>       a.aob=b;
>       b.aob=a;
>       c.aob=a.aob;
>       A d= new A().aob=new A();
>       **c=b**; //(1)
>
> It becomes eligible at (1).
>
> The other object eligible for GC is at statement
>
> A d=**new A()**.aob=*new A()*;
>
> Here the object created in the text in bold will be eligible for GC. The object in italicized text will be assigned to d.

Comment: I agree! In general, the objects that are eligible for GC are the ones that cannot be reached by any reference. In more complicated scenarios, they are "isles" if inter-referenced objects that are not referenced by other objects outside that "isle".